# Python,запустить два цикла одновременно

Tags: python

я новичок в питоне,хотел бы узнать как можно две функции в которых есть бесконечный цикл,объединить.
Получается одна функция воспроизводит анимацию и другая,но из за того что у них цикл не прерывается 
запускается только первая функция(первая анимация)а вторая не может,хочу запустить их в одном окне и чтобы
они одновременно работали.

Comment: почитайте про потоки

Comment: Приведите код иначе ничего непонятно

Comment: Нужно ещё учитывать, что с GUI может обычно работать только какой-то один тред, поэтому лучше обновлять GUI в основном потоке, а дополнительные потоки пусть генерируют для этого потока нужные данные.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот код: Проверил работает: Но хотелось бы более подробно задачу. Если Вы пишите игру. То в pygame есть свой цикл и правила выполнения анимаций. Но если не играи нужен именно thread то код ниже:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


class Thread1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10000):
            time.sleep(1)
            print("1")

class Thread2(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10000):
            time.sleep(1)
            print("2")

t1 = Thread1()
t1.start()
t2 = Thread2()
t2.start() 


result:
1
2
1
2
```

Comment: получается у меня одна функция отрисовывает падающие снежинки бесконечно,а другая рисует радугу у которой меняются цвета,и мне нужно их совместить так скажем в одну программу,и вот думаю с помощью потоков делать(но это я как понял не много нето),или придеться совмещать куски кодов этих функций в одну

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
def dd1(n):
    pass
def dd2(n):
    pass
            
t1 = Thread(target=dd1, args=('10'))
t2 = Thread(target=dd2, args=('10'))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: from threading import Thread пробовал,не то что нужно либо не так делаю,первая анимация работает(функция) а когда запускается вторая,первая замирает.